# How to store a print output to variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wanted to know if there was a way to reproduce an output from one section of a code to the end of the code. So I am assuming I need to assign a variable to the `print output` function. Anyway this is part of my code that I want to store variable output to a variable and reproduce an output anywhere in my code:

```
for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[data_location]:
        scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
        busnum = int(busnum)
        output='Bus #: {}\t Area Station: {}\t New Load Total: {} MW\t'
        print(output.format(busnum,busname,scaled_power))
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to assign the result of `output.format` to a variable; not the value of the `print` function.

```
formatted_output = output.format(busnum, busname, scaled_power)
```

The `print` function will always return `None`. In your loop, if you need the output for each iteration, store them in a `list`.

```
outputs = []

for busnum, busname, scaled_power in busses_in_year[data_location]:
    scaled_power = float(scaled_power)
    busnum = int(busnum)
    output = 'Bus #: {}\t Area Station: {}\t New Load Total: {} MW\t'
    formatted = output.format(busnum, busname, scaled_power)
    outputs.append(formatted)
    print(formatted)
```

Comment: what is `outputs[]`

Comment: @mike: `outputs` is defined as an empty list. Elements are being added to the list with `output.append(formatted)` within the loop. [Check out the documentation for `list`.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: I receive error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: @mike: I had typed `output` rather than `outputs`. I've made the correction in my answer.

Comment: Am I suppose to write this in the code I have right now. Also the goal was to output this statement at the end of my code. so I tried using code you gave me at the end of my code and it sill gives me same error